# Can't change ComboBox selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I've been all day trying to make this work properly, but it seems I'm unable.

The first thing I do is populate a combobox with the list of voices installed on system. Once that the combobox is properly populated with all the voices, I can't select any value from the combobox.

Where is the problem?

```
public class ComboData
{
public int _Id { get; set; }
public string _Name { get; set; }
}

public void accSettings()
{
SpeechSynthesizer speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();

List<ComboData> ListData = new List<ComboData>();

int a = 1;
foreach (InstalledVoice voice in speaker.GetInstalledVoices())
{
    VoiceInfo info = voice.VoiceInfo;
    ListData.Add(new ComboData { _Id = a, _Name = info.Name });
    a++;
}

VoiceList.ItemsSource = ListData;
VoiceList.DisplayMemberPath = "_Name";
VoiceList.SelectedValuePath = "_Id";

VoiceList.SelectedValue = "1";
}
```

And this is the XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="VoiceList" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

All the XAML related to my problem:

```
<Window x:Class="UltimateParkinson.UltimateView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="CIRENC - Base de Datos" Height="582" Width="830" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Closed="Window_Closed">
<ContentControl x:Name="content_ajustes" Margin="85,67,15,50" UseLayoutRounding="False" Visibility="Visible">
    <Grid Margin="0" Background="#FFF9F9F9">
        <TabControl x:Name="PreferencesTab" Margin="0" SelectionChanged="PreferencesTab_SelectionChanged">
            <TabItem Header="Accesibilidad">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Desde aquí puedes establecer los ajustes de accesibilidad de la aplicación." VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <GroupBox Header="Lector de Textos" Margin="10,35,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid Margin="0">
                            <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="¿Activar el lector de textos?" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                                <RadioButton x:Name="readerYes" Margin="10,0,10,0" Content="Si"/>
                                <RadioButton x:Name="readerNo" Margin="10,0,10,0" Content="No"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="¿Qué voz deséa utilizar?" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="VoiceList" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="11" Margin="15,0,10,0" Text="* Las voces están instaladas en tú sistema y son ajenas a la aplicación."></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Velocidad de lectura" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="VoicePitch" Margin="10,0,0,15" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="-2"/>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="-1"/>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="0"/>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="2"/>
                                </ComboBox>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,10,0" Text="*Puedes probar la voz aquí." FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="11"></TextBlock>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0,10,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Texto de prueba." Padding="0,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
                                    <Button Content="Vista Previa" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="5" Margin="10,0,0,10" ></Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </GroupBox>
                    <Button x:Name="guardarAcc" Padding="5" Content="Guardar" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="guardarAcc_Click"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</ContentControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: _I can't select any values_. Is this because the control is grayed out? Are you sure that `Enabled` is not set to false? Look through the properties in the designer to see if some rogue option is on.

Comment: Can you show the XAML for the VoiceList?

Comment: @gunr2171 The control is correctly enabled, I can display the dropdown list, the problem is once I click one of the combobox items nothing happens, the dropdown list dissapears like when you select an item but nothing is selected afterward.

Comment: (this is coming from a WinForms background) Do you have a `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler. How does your code know how to do anything once the selection has been made?

Comment: @gunr2171 I didn't add any kind of event handler to the combobox. Could it be on another place?

Comment: On the other hand, as you can see I've another combobox which is working properly, the only difference is that VoiceList combobox is being populated programmatically.

Comment: @gunr2171 found the problem... I was calling AccSettings() from the SelectionChanged of TabControl, I didn't know that changing a combobox value would trigger it... anyway I'm still wondering why it only happens with one of the comboboxes. 

Anyway at least now I can make it work someway. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is accSettings() being called more than once?  Put a breakpoint there and see.  If you click an item, and then accSettings() gets called again, the combobox will be reset to its initial values and your selection will be lost.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found, I was calling it from the ControlTab selection changed event, I thought it would only trigger when changing between tabs, I was wrong. Thanks